# Variables craziness, rounding number (int,double etc.)

Tags: java, math, variables, numbers

This is mine code, not fully finished, and sorry for Polish language but it's easy to get it.
http://pastebin.com/QPmVaPFv
So, this is about vet, 4 variables are for price per visitor:
1. Big dog
2. Medium dog
3. Small dog
4.cat
After that next 4 variables are for numbers of visitor, same as before (big,medium,small,cat etc.)

Then text says: 
every 5th big dog owner got 10% discount
every 3rd medium owner got 50% discount
every 4th cat owner got price at 1$ i.e

```
double zdpies=ldpies/5.;
double zspies=lspies/3.;
double zkot=ckot/4.;
```

This is that part with discounts

after that i made variables with calculations on discounted price

```
double cdpiespromo=cdpies/10.; Big dog
double cspiespromo=cspies/50.; medium dog
double ckotpromo=1; Cat
```

Then i made calculation for final price i.e for normal price without discount

--- cena normalna: 21.6 x 51.0 = 1101.6000000000001

Process completed.

And i got that strange numbers, 51. is ok but 21.6 is wrong that must be 22 not 21.6. When i use "int" it says there is "loss of precision", any ideas how to fix that ?

Here are last variables for calculating final price discounted and without discount.

```
double idp=ldpies-zdpies; this calculates numbers of visitors without discount
double idc=idp*cdpies; this calculates price number of visitor * normalpriceofbigdog.
```

Comment: You need to use a base 10 decimal data type rather than a base 2 floating point type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great article on using float, double, BigDecimal etc for doing calculation here http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html

Bottom line is that there is no perfect solution.

Comment: Nice article, but got another question are there any other solution for that if i.e i don't have that on studies i.e Bigdecimal itp ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use float or double to do financial calculations, use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Since dealing with BigDecimal is a little cumbersome, I wrote a [BdHelper](https://github.com/stivlo/obliquid-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/org/obliquid/helpers/BdHelper.java) class, to shorten the code necessary for certain operations/conversions. The class is not meant to be complete, I really wrote only the methods that I needed, but you get the idea.

[Jon Skeet talked about the pain of using floating point numbers](http://vimeo.com/7516539) in StackOverflow Dev Days London.

Answer (score 0):

Go With [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).
Here's a good start: [Make cents with BigDecimal - JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2001/jw-0601-cents.html).